# Custom Permalinks Break Search Pagination

Tags: search, query, pagination, paged

So I'm having a weird issue that I've never seen.

I have a search.php set up like this:

```
 
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; 
query_posts($query_string . '&paged=' . $paged); 

if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    // post stuff
endwhile; else:

endif;

pagination();
```

If I use anything but the default permalink structure, it breaks the pagination and returns a 404 and the second page.

Ant ideas?

Comment: Can you post a bit more context, please? What's in `$query_string` and where do you get it from?

Comment: There is no other context. That is all of the necessary info for the search.php template. $query_string prevents query_posts from ignoring the search query.

Comment: Okay, just noticed something really strange. First of all, I'm pretty sure this is only an issue with 3.1 Second, if I hold my mouse over a pagination link (such as page 1, page 2, etc) the url is http://my-site.com/blogname/blogname/page/#. Notice how blogname is repeated twice? Now what is even weirder is that it only does this if the /page/ parameter is not already in the url, such as when I'm on the very first page. If I manually change the url to http://my-site.com/blogname/page/2, everything works fine.

Comment: Oh, and it all works perfectly fine when on archive or blog pages.

Comment: Alright, I've solved the problem. Turns out that you should never use action="<?php bloginfo('url');?>" for searchform.php. It will work perfectly fine in terms of search results, but it will break the pagination, when using 3.1. Instead, you should use <?php echo home_url();?> for the form action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I've solved the problem. Turns out that you should never use action="" for searchform.php. It will work perfectly fine in terms of search results, but it will break the pagination, when using 3.1. Instead, you should use  for the form action.